# Two Dimensional Array Perimeter and Initializing Data

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, initialization, character

I am a beginner in java, so please go easy on me. I am working on a practice method problem that deals with two dimensional arrays. The problem is a method that tells you to take a two dimensional array of characters named array as a parameter. It then wants you to initialize all of the elements of the array to ‘x’ except for the perimeter (first and last column, and first and last row) that is initialized to ‘o’.

My question is how do you just initialize each element to represent x and y in a two dimensional array and how do you go about initializing each row and column element for the perimeter? 
For example a two dimensional array that creates 3 rows by 4 columns-

```
char[][] table = new char[3][4]
```

-would fill the table's outside perimeter with only o's and the rest inside would be filled with x's correct?

Is this essentially what the output would look like?

```
  { o, o, o, o},
  { o, x, x, o},
  { o, o, o, o},
```

Also, can someone just steer me in the right direction if I am no where close to understanding the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is best handled as two separate problems:

1. Initialize the first and last rows to 'o'
2. Initialize the remaining rows

The first problem is easy to solve: iterate through the first and last rows and set each element to 'o'.  The second problem is broken down to

2a. Initialize the first and last column to 'o'

2b. Initialize the remaining columns to 'x'

Assuming a row has a length of `length`, this is solved with

```
array[0] = 'o';
array[length - 1] - 'o';
for(int i = 1; i < length - 1; i++)
    array[i] = 'x'
```

Answer (score 0):

A `new` int array  will be initialized to all zeroes.

So int[][] array = new int[3][4];

would look like

```
{0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0}
{0,0,0,0}
```

You'll have to do the work of setting the perimeter yourself

What you'll want is to nest some loops and determine where you are in the array and set accordingly:
(pseudocode)

```
for i loop through array.length
    for j loop through array[i].length
        if i == first element or i == last element or j == first element or j == last element
             then array[i][j] = perimeter value
        else
             array[i][j] = center value
```

An array of n length has n elements, referred to by 0 to n-1, so if you had an array like this

```
{1,2,3,4}
```

array[0] would be 1, this is because Java arrays are zero based.

Given that, the first will always be 0 and the last will be length-1

Comment: Alright, I have a better understanding of how to approach the problem. One question though. How do I find the first and last element for the if statement? would something like row == array[0].length be correct way to state the first element I am looking for? That is given that I created the new array first with that array[0].length inside